# para qué se usa "implements OnInit" en angular?

Tags: angular

estoy intentando entender angular y tengo dudas sobre este comando. `implements OnInit` he leido la documentación, pero no me ha quedado claro, no sé que diferencia existe si tan solo uso ´ngOnInit()` en lugar de utilizar esto. muchas gracias

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
  // ...
 }
}
```

aprovecho para preguntar, si alguien sabe que quiere decir esto: `Array<Object>`, bastaria con solo dejarlo como coches:Array? o que diferencias hay?

```
 coches:Array<Object>=["Carro", "auto"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1- Acerca de interfaz OnInit**

La implementación de la interfaz [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) **no** es obligatoria, o mejor dicho, [técnicamente es opcional](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#interfaces-are-optional-technically).

Más bien, su uso es una [Buena Práctica](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-09-01) que debe ser utilizada para evitar errores, por ejemplo, escribir `onInit` en lugar de `ngOnInit`, lo que causaría que el método no sea llamado.

Para comprobar que no es obligatoria basta con probar con un código como el siguiente:

```
class MyComponent { // <- interfaz OnInit no implementada
  ngOnInit() {
  // el método (hook) será llamado aunque no haya sido implementada la interfaz 
 }
}
```

Esto sucede porque el código TypeScript es "transpilado" (traducido/compilado) a código JavaScript.

Extraído literalmente del link mencionado se puede leer que:

> Fortunately, they aren't necessary [*las interfaces*]. You don't have to add the lifecycle hook interfaces to directives and components to benefit from the hooks themselves.
>
> Angular instead inspects directive and component
>   classes and calls the hook methods if they are defined. Angular finds
>   and calls methods like ngOnInit(), with or without the interfaces

**2- Acerca de la declaración de Array**

`Array<Object>` puede ser usado para la declaración de un arreglo de objetos. Por ejemplo:

`let arr: Array<Object>;`

También pudiera ser declarado de la siguiente forma:

`let arr: Object[];`

Answer (score 0):

Ese implements OnInit le indica a Angular que, una vez se ha completado la instanciación del componente (MyComponent en tu caso) y, por tanto, ya se ha hecho toda la vinculación de propiedades (bindings) y toda la parte de inyección de dependencias ha quedado resuelta, ha de ejecutar un método llamado ngOnInit() donde, por regla general, implementarás el código necesario para la inicialización de tu componente.

Si no añades el implements, Angular no invocará al método ngOnInit, por mucho que tú lo hayas declarado.

Y respecto a tu segunda pregunta, en Typescript tienes dos opciones para declarar arrays. La primera es como has indicado en tu ejemplo:

```
let coches: Array<Object>...
```

Aquí estás usando la clase Array que usa genéricos y, por tanto, necesita que se especifique el tipo de sus elementos.

La segunda opción es la "clásica":

```
let coches: Object[]...
```

Comment: _Si no añades el implements, Angular no invocará al método ngOnInit, por mucho que tú lo hayas declarado_. **Esto es falso**, por favor, mira [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171202/para-qu%C3%A9-se-usa-implements-oninit-en-angular/172913#172913)